# Laravel Sql query groupBy and Order

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need some help to make a query.

[Database tabless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkxw9.png)

*Example:*
The ***user*** inserts a **actor** name(name and surname) and i need to loop over all the **movies** and then retrieve which **category** has more occurrences.

I need some help to make the query(this one is only a sketch):

```
$src=array("Leonardo","DiCaprio");
     $film2=film::with('category')->with('actor')->wherehas('actor', function($q) use($src){
                                  $q->where('first_name', $src[0])->where('last_name', $src[1]);
                                })->wherehas('category', function($qr){
                                  $qr->groupBy('name')->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
                                })->FIRST();
```

> model Film:

```
class film extends Model{
    protected $table = "film";  
    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['film_id', 'title', 'length'];

    public function category(){
         return $this->belongsToMany(category::class,'film_category', 'film_id', 'category_id');
    }
    public function actor(){
          return $this->belongsToMany(actor::class,'film_actor', 'film_id', 'actor_id');
    }
}
```

> model Actor:

```
class actor extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'actor_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['actor_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']; 
}
```

> model Category:

```
class category extends Model{
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['category_id','name'];


    public function film(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(film::class,'film_category', 'category_id', 'film_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution**:

*In Actor.php add Join*

```
 public function filmActor(){
     return $this->hasMany(FilmActor::class, 'actor_id','actor_id');
 }
```

*Find the actor with filmActor join table*

```
 $src=array("Leonardo","DiCaprio");
 $actor=Actor::whereHas('filmActor')->where(['first_name' => $src[0],'last_name'=> $src[1]])->first();
```

*Put film_id in the array*

```
 foreach($actor->filmActor as $film){
      $filmIds[]=$film->film_id;
 }
```

*Get FilmCategory who have filmIds*

```
$filmCategory=FilmCategory::whereIn('film_id',$filmIds)->get();
```

*Put category_id in the array*

```
 foreach($filmCategory as $category){
      $categoryIds[]=$category->category_id;
 }
```

*Count how much is duplicate category_id*

```
 $count =array_count_values($categoryIds);
```

*Get the higher counted* `$max =  max($count);`
*Get the key of max which is category_id*  `$key = array_search($max, $count);`

*Here is the category who has more occurrences.*

```
 $category=Category::where('category_id',$key)->first();
```